# Finding limit of function from limit of derivative.

Tags: real-analysis

any hints on this question, will the mean value theorem be used here?

> Suppose that $f$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$, and $\lim_{x \to +\infty}$$f'(x)=M$, show that $\lim_{x \to +\infty}$$(f(x+1)-(f(x))$ exists and find it.

Comment: Can you write $f(x+1)-f(x)$ in a different way involving the derivative?

Comment: @TooOldforMath: I think your answer was basically correct and the only thing you could probably remark (and let all the rest for the OP to complete) is that since $\;f'(x)\xrightarrow[x\to\infty]{} M\;$ , then this is true *no matter how the variable* $\;x\;$ "goes" to infinity. From here that if $\;\zeta_x\to\infty\;$ then we're done. That "if" part is the only thing that needs a little more work (very little, imo) and can safely be let to the OP (although you addressed this question in your comments).

Comment: @ABC I can't see how DonAntonio's comment is wrong. Could you please add some explanation and even your solution to the OP's question?

Comment: Take $e>0$. Then there is $N>0$ such that $|f'(x)-M|<e$ for all $x>N$. Now, $|f(x+1)-f(x)-M|=|f'(r)-M|<e$, for $x>N$.

Comment: @ABC, I still can't see how the other comment is wrong. You  seem to have used the IVT for differentiable functions in your last equality, which seems to be what was used by TooOldforMath and also in the other answer.

Comment: @Timbuc You can't see it, because what is wrong is about a comment in the answer that was deleted. It is true that the answer needed very little to get corrected. What is wrong is that the comment in that answer wasn't giving the right explanation that was missing.

Comment: ABC, by the comment I suppose the deleted answer was about taking limits (from the "no matter how the variable tends to infinity" and the $\;\zeta_x\to \infty\;$), and this is what I'd like to know why you think it is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: By the Mean Value Theorem, we know that $f(x+1)-f(x)=f'(\xi)$ for some $\xi\in (x,x+1)$.